list indexing in print function
list indexing error in print function
todos = []
print("Welcome to todo app")

while True:
    print("What do you want to do? ")
    user_action = input("'add', 'show', 'edit' , 'delete' or 'exit': ").lower().strip()

    match user_action:
        case 'add':
            todo = input("Enter a todo: ")
            todos.append(todo)

        case 'show':
            i = 1
            for item in todos:
                print(f"{i}. {item}")
                i += 1

        case 'edit':
            edit_todo_index = int(input("Enter number of todo which you want to edit: "))
            # todos[editing_todo_index] = input("Enter new todo: ")
            todos.__setitem__(edit_todo_index - 1, input("Enter a new todo: "))

        case 'delete':
            todo_index = int(input("which todo you want to delete: "))
            deleting_todo = todos[todo_index - 1]
            todos.remove(deleting_todo)
            print(f"todo '{todos[todo_index - 1]}' wad deleted successfully")

        case 'exit':
            break

if len(todos) > 0:
    print(f"\n$$$ Todo app was created Successfully $$$\n")
else:
    print(f"\n$$$ todo app is empyt $$$\n")

I tried to case "delete"
in print function list indexing not working as expected
print(f"todo '{todos[todo_index - 1]}' wad deleted successfully")
todos[todo_index - 1] not calculating the todo_index - 1 formula

be careful when using the remove method on a list, as in some_list.remove(value). It removes the first occurrence of value in some_list. To remove a specific element by its index, you should do del some_list[index] instead

you have deleted the todos[todo_index - 1] so you cannot access it. use the copy and print it.
Updated code:
case 'delete':
    todo_index = int(input("which todo you want to delete: "))
    deleting_todo = todos[todo_index - 1]
    todos.remove(deleting_todo)
    print(f"todo '{deleting_todo}' wad deleted successfully")

